# How can I cite document in the type of "author(year)" under biblatex?

Tags: latex

I used the order "\citet{}" under biblatex and it shows error:" unbalanced parentheses or brackets" and "unmatched \bibcloseparen". How can I cite document in the type of "author(year)" under biblatex? (Besides, I tried \cite{} but the result is (author,year).)

Comment: please make a [mre] that allows us to reproduce your problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
  sorting=ynt
  ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
Just have a look at~\cite{wikibook}.

Described by Laura Lion~\cite[9]{lion2010}.


\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}




% ==============content of mybib.bib===============
%   
%@book{lion2010,
%   author       = {Laura Lion and  Gabrielle Giraffe and Carl Capybara},
%   title        = {The dangers of asking the wrong question},
%   publisher    = {publishing house},
%   date         = {2010},
%   keywords     = {trusted},
%}
%@online{wikibook,
%   title        = {Generating Bibliographies with biblatex and biber},
%   organization = {Wikibooks},
%   date         = {2016},
%   urldate      = {2016-03-07},
%   url          = {https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Generating_Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber},
%   keywords     = {untrusted},
%}
```

gives you:

[image]